# Is it true that $f(e) \ne g(\pi) \,\,\forall f,g$ are non zero algebraic functions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Just a random question that popped in my head. This is of course non true if we consider just irrationals.
Moreover, (assuming above holds) does there exists some sort of equivalence class for transcendentals such that $x\sim y$ iff $\exists f,g$ non zero algebraic st $f(x)=g(y)$.
If it does, then for each given transcendental, is it dense on $\mathbb R$?

Please feel free to add tags as I'm not sure about category for this question

Comment: By algebraic, do you mean $f,g\in\mathbb Z[x]$?

Comment: @ajotatxe i meants functions. I have added that. For the other comment, I'm not sure what that means. By algebraic functions, I mean something like polynomials, but rational powers are also allowed. Also $f/g$ is also algebraic given $f,g$ are algebraic

Comment: I think that the question is if $\pi$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(e)$.

Comment: @ajotatxe How is $\mathbb Q(e)$ defined?

Comment: @ajotatxe OP is allowing rational powers aswell

Comment: @ajotatxe , algebraic coefficients and division by other such functions aswell

Comment: @Anvit It doesn't matter: $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ if it is algebraic over the field of algebraic numbers.

Comment: Do you allow infinite polynomials? F. ex. $$1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout They would make it trivially false, no? ;)

Comment: @Anvit Indeed! Just checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not known if $e+\pi$ is algebraic or not.

Comment: you mean algebraic or not?